# Referencing a dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll

When I reference a dll in c#, it has my local path. So when I run it on another computer it can't find it. How can I add a dll so it isn't looking in my local folder?

When I run my program on another computer it says "can't find namespace, are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?"

I must be googling the wrong key words because I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I assume you're copying your dll along with your app to the remote computer?

Comment: You would get that error if you tried to *compile* the program on another computer. If you tried to *run* it you'd just get a failure. Why don't you just copy the DLL along with your program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on it in the References area, go to properties, and set "Copy Local" to True. This will copy the dll into your output/bin folder for distribution and should solve the dependency on a machine without the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly reference don't have the path (local or whatever). Just the referenced assembly names. You can verify it yourself with ildasm, and double click on the assembly manifest.

The referred assembly has to be accessible on the other machine. Either on the same directory, or in the search path, or in the GAC. It is your deployment program (script, setup, or otherwise) that has to make sure you deploy all the dependency on the client machine.