# De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart dll not in exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dll, dllimport

I am building a c# program using visual studio 2013, i needed to display some charts, so i decided to use [MetroChart](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/). After referencing the dll to my project, i was able to run my project and play with the graphics. The problem is that i can't execute the .exe file in any other PC's or folder outside the debug folder of my visual studio 2013. After the program crashes it gives me this error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in x.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=d5b8d1bbc99c4a2a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

How can i get my .exe to have the dll inside so it can find it? or how should it be? i referenced other dll's in the past and everything went fine.

Comment: DLL inside the exe is [not exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830127/referencing-a-dll-in-c-sharp) what you want.

Comment: You should distribute the .dll's your application is using alongside your application.